# Creating numbering for math compendium in Adobe InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, workflow, numbering, mathematics, lists

I am currently as the teacher of a math class creating a math compendium as a complement to the course book that I feel lack some crucial parts.

Now The compendie is mostly constructed from scanned material and after fighting with OCR software without much luck I decided to go mostly for pure images.
I am using Photoshop to work the images and Indesign to put together the compendium. The compendium is currently at 60 pages sized in A4. Designwise the pages consist of a one or two column designs with information and tasks.

**What I want to achieve is** numbering for the different tasks in my compendium say working in 1000's for chapter 1 2000 for chapter 2 etc. 
I have tried using the normal numbering list system but as I am using images for my main content lists seem to work poorly, at least at first sight, perhaps you can customize them but I dont see how to do that.

Also since the distances between tasks are variable I would need some decently easy way to edit position of the numbers, perhaps just vertically to make editing and adding new numbers easy. Perhaps a system of standard positioning or something similar could be used, master layouts?.

Now I am looking for ways to do this decently fast, do you have any tips or advice on how this could be done? Similar questions on the forum seems to indicate methods like cross referencing or anchor points, but I cannot see how to implement those methods here and since I am not familiar with the software I need your help :).

I will add some actual images from the compendie once I get home from work and have access, do ask if anything feels unclear.

[image: Example page]

Comment: Do you need a live numbering, because you for example want insert a new item between items 2034 and 2035? Could you accept  decimals for ex. 2034.1 ? That would not demand total renumbering the rest of the items and all cross-references. OTHER: I would not trash the handmades because even your ultra-low resolution screenshot reveals the remarkably fine work. Today such ability is not common.

Comment: No, I am completely fine without live numbering, I could add .1 or other if I need to make adjustments, ( although it would be nice to know how that could be done for further projects). The compendie is basicly done and I doubt I will haveto rearrange things after adding the numbering., OTHER, thanks, however this screenshot is just a google image used as a random example.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need live numbering, simply add a textbox for the identifier. InDesign allow freeform textboxes. An example:

[image]

The full display, when writing is this:

[image]

Construct master pages to keep the common elements such as page numbers in good shape. Create styles for titles, tables and other text types.